# Validation rule for 3 IFs and 1 OR condition to show error

Tags: validation, validation-rule

I need help to create a Validation rule

I have 4 picklist fields
Region- US, EUR, EU, ASIA, AUS
Country- NAMES OF COUNTRIES
State- STATE NAMES
City- City names.

I want to show error when
IF(Region=US AND If(country=South America) AND (State='BRAZIL') AND(If city= Brasilia OR SAO PAULO OR SALVADOR.

Comment: You seem to have a decent start on what you'd need for your validation formula, so what have you tried? Where are you stuck? If you're getting an error, you should include the full text of the error exactly as it appears. [edit] your question to add that information.

Comment: Also, this seems like something that would possibly be a better fit for _dependent picklists_ (i.e. configuring one picklist to show specific values based on the selected value of another picklist).

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if below validation rule works for you.

```
AND( ISPICKVAL( Region__c ,'US'), ISPICKVAL( Country__c ,'South America'), ISPICKVAL( State__c ,'BRAZIL'),OR( ISPICKVAL( City__c ,'Brasilia'), ISPICKVAL(City__c,'SAO PAULO'), ISPICKVAL(City__c,'SALVADOR') ) )
```

Check the below trialhead link to know more about validation rule using picklist fields.

> https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/advanced_formulas/picklist_formulas